# How to show Menu on button press instead of right mouse click in os x

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa

When I assign a Menu to a button, the menu will be shown when the user right click the button.

I want to open the menu when the user left click the button.

Something similar to this:

[image]

---

I got it working using this code, However the menu is shown at the top right corner of my screen. What am I doing wrong?

```
@IBOutlet var meeenu: NSMenu!
@IBAction func Options(sender: NSButtonCell) {
    meeenu.popUpMenuPositioningItem(meeenu.itemAtIndex(0), atLocation: NSEvent.mouseLocation(), inView: self.view)
}
```

Comment: There are methods provided by `NSMenu` to display the menu, what have you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: @CRD Can you introduce me to one of them? I have just this second tried `sender.menu?.popUpMenuPositioningItem(sender.menu?.itemAtIndex(0), atLocation: NSEvent.mouseLocation(), inView: self.view)` **but it didn't work**

Comment: Edit your question and add your code and state what went wrong. With that information somebody might be able to help you.

Comment: It worked finally, but the menu is not showing at the mouse location? instead it's on the right top corner of my screen? Anything you could help with?

Comment: Never mind it worked! `self.view -> nil` Fixed it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got it working finally using this code:

```
@IBOutlet var meeenu: NSMenu!
@IBAction func Options(sender: NSButtonCell) {
    meeenu.popUpMenuPositioningItem(meeenu.itemAtIndex(0), atLocation: NSEvent.mouseLocation(), inView: nil)
}
```

Comment: Note that for swift 5 the function would be:   `meeenu.popUp(positioning: meenu.item(at: 0), at: NSEvent.mouseLocation, in: self.view)`

Comment: The menu item is not enabled...Do you know why?.

Comment: @AshishGupta Yes, you actually have to connect the item to a function. Then it will be enabled.